# Exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script3.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 64

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Using below versions for Performance Testing:
1.JMeter version - 5.5
2.Chrome Browser version - 115.0.5790.171 (Official Build) (64-bit)
3.Downloaded Chrome Web Driver Config - 115.0.5790.170
4.Javac - 20.0.1

Getting as **Exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script3.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 64.**

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64.**

Could anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) comes with [Groovy 3.0.11](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/gradle.properties#L92) which doesn't support Java 20

You need to take one of the following actions:

1. Downgrade Java to a lower version, the minimum you can run JMeter 5.5 with is [Java 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/)
2. Try [JMeter's nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html), it might be the case it contains Groovy 4+
3. Manually upgrade Groovy libraries in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) to the version you want/need.

You might want to consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) in any case, [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)